# Write a file with dd over ssh

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, io-redirection, dd

I want to write a .img file to a hdd over ssh.

Host A want to execute dd to write the img file to /dev/sda . The dd file is located at Host B.

How should the command look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
(from hosta) ssh hostb cat /the/file.img | dd of=/dev/sda
```

or

```
(from hostb) ssh hosta dd of=/dev/sda < /the/file.img
```

With ssh (and rsh before it) the I/O redirection happens on the local host unless you quote it to pass it through to the remote host.  Compare these three commands (in all cases the `date` command runs on `rmthost`), but:

```
ssh rmthost date > /tmp/thedate                    ! local file written
ssh rmthost 'date > /tmp/thedate'                  ! remote file written
ssh rmthost date '>' /tmp/thedate                  ! remote file written
```